# Hasn't the <embed> tag been around for a while?

Tags: html, embed

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_embed.asp) and [Pluralsight's](http://www.pluralsight-training.net) HTML5 course, the `<embed>` tag is "new" to HTML5. But I've been using it since...forever, and it works in any browser i've tested it against. [This](http://grace-pca.net/recent-sermons) page for example, uses the `<embed>` tag and it works in all browsers.

Why? Was it just a draft that got implemented ahead of time by eager browser makers?

Comment: Its funny how i had a debate about this yesterday here at stackoverflow. Look at w3fools.com.

Comment: @AaterSuleman yeah, I've seen it. :) Are you saying W3Schools is wrong about this?

Comment: Yes. I guess so. Yesterday I was defending w3schools site but my opponents convinced me that they have lots of bugs your independent observation also supports their claim so I give up:)

Comment: @Aater: Actually, I've just done some research. It seems that in this case at least W3Schools seems to be accurate, as much as it pains me to say it. See my answer for more info and links to proof.

Comment: This is an example of "paying the cow paths," a design principle for HTML5.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html-design-principles/#pave-the-cowpaths

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/embed) do agree with W3Schools ([for once](http://w3fools.com/)), but you are right. `<embed>` has been in use for ages but was standardized properly for HTML5.

HTML 4 officially used [`<object>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/objects.html#h-13.5). Contrary to several sources which state `<embed>` was deprecated in HTML 4, I can't find any mention of it in the [HTML 3](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/Contents.html) [DTD](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/html3.dtd) (or in [3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32)), which means it was probably never standardized officially. [HTML 2](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_toc.html) seems to be even less evolved (as one might expect). There is plenty of documentation about `<applet>`, but I can't find a single mention about `<embed>` anywhere official.

Answer (score 3):

After a little research and help from you guys, I found that the `<embed>` tag was originally introduced by Netscape as a means to display images and similar content.  Apparently it was never officially implemented into a standard (I checked the HTML 3 and both XHTML standards on W3C). Naturally though Internet Explorer implemented it in order to combat Netscape, and it went from there.

http://1997.webhistory.org/www.lists/www-talk.1995q3/0578.html

[http://w3.org/](http://w3.org)

Comment: As I understand it, `<embed>` wasn't liked at the time by the people who wrote the HTML4 standard, because it was a void element, and therefore authors couldn't add fallback content in the event that the user was using a browser that didn't support embed. In that sense `<object>` was superior, so its use was encouraged by standardization. Embed was "discouraged" rather than "deprecated". There aren't really any browsers that don't support embed now, and the HTML5 approach to fallback content is somewhat different, so it wasn't really an issue with HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

`embed` wasn't part of W3C standards but was useful enough for browsers to support it. HTML5 takes a pragmatic approach to what is, so it's here.

Comment: @Thomas I'm going to Google that but my instinct is it's from IE vs Netscape a long time ago

Answer (score 1):

The `<embed>` tag <del>has in fact been around for a while, but it was deprecated in HTML4 and XHTML1. It</del> was <del>re-</del>introduced in HTML5.

** Corrected. :)

Comment: so it was valid in HTML3? oh wait, there was no HTML3... or was there no JS3... anyways, it was valid in a previous HTML?

Comment: May be W3 schools is right. The debate is still on. lol. (see above comments for reference)

Comment: Ah, just checked I thought it was in 3.2. I got it confused with the applet tag. Looks like its "new" then. :)

Comment: @Thomas Check out my answer. I've traced all the specs right back to HTML2, and there's no mention of `<embed>` anywhere, though there's plenty about `<applet>` and similar.