# Is embed tag new in HTML5?

Tags: css, html, audio, embed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hasn't the <embed> tag been around for a while?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972555/hasnt-the-embed-tag-been-around-for-a-while)

The w3c page says  is new in html5.
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_embed.asp

However i have been seeing embed tag from long time..

I am a bit confused now .please help.

Comment: [obligatory w3fools reference](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: w3schools.com has nothing at all to do with the real W3, don't trust them.

Comment: *"The w3c page says is new in html5."* followed *"http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_embed.asp"* is a non-sequitur. The W3C page for HTML is [here](http://www.w3.org/html/), the HTML5 spec is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/). w3schools has nothing to do with the W3C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<EMBED ...>` is not a part of the HTML
>   4 or xHTML 1 specifications, but it is
>   still widely supported by modern
>   browsers. Unlike other tags, the
>   attributes used by  depend
>   on the type of plugin being used (this
>   odd free-attribute concept is why
>   `<EMBED ...>` has been rejected by the
>   HTML standards makers).

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/embeddedobjects/_EMBED.html

Answer (score 3):

The embed element is now formally included in the HTML5 specification. It was an element that's been around for awhile, but one that would never validate.

Answer (score 1):

see:
[Hasn't the <embed> tag been around for a while?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972555/hasnt-the-embed-tag-been-around-for-a-while)

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong, and that's not the W3C page. It's here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/ embed is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-embed-element

See this page for lots of reasons not to use that other site : http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

The EMBED tag was deprecated in favour of the OBJET tag in previous version of HTML. If my memory serves me right, the EMBED tag used to be proprietary to Netscape and was often wrapped inside an OBJECT tag.

Comment: It was not deprecated.  It's not part of the HTML 4 or XHTML specs.