# Is <embed> a valid HTML5 tag?

Tags: html

I am aware I can use the  tag in html5. However, is it a valid tag as part of html5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hasn't the <embed> tag been around for a while?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972555/hasnt-the-embed-tag-been-around-for-a-while)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hasn't the <embed> tag been around for a while?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972555/hasnt-the-embed-tag-been-around-for-a-while)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. The  tag is part of the HTML5 language, which allows seamless integration with applications, videos, or other web content which can be embedded.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-embed-element).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-embed-element

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See [the `embed` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-embed-element).